# Unable to browse few MySql tables using xampp (phpMyAdmin3.1.1) in rhel6.2

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp, rhel

I am having a issue while accessing the Mysqldatabase tables using xampp. According to my requirement few tables were dynamically created having following properties

```
   Columns >700
   Collation :latin1_swedish_ci
   Type:MyISAM
   Size 60KB to 600KB
```

Earlier I was using rhel5 and phpMyAdmin2.10.3, I was able to browse all the tables of the database. Now, I upgraded the system to rhel6.2 and using xampp1.7.7 having phpMyAdmin3.1.1, with this I am able to browse almost all the tables except few as described above. All the other tables with more than the above mentioned size is getting loaded, but these few tables having columns more than 700 are not getting loaded.

Please help me to find the solution..

Comment: What happens when you try to view those tables?

Comment: @IsaacBennetch, it shows loading and then nothing gets loaded.

Comment: If you go to the Structure tab, does it show all ~700 columns or are there problems on that page as well?